# Kivy: ScreenManager stretches over the whole window

Tags: kivy

I have a problem with ScreenManager and Screen in kivy file. I want to have a ScreenManager in BoxLayout, and it work when I don't use .kv file. But when I use kivy file, ScreenManager with "ContentScreenManager" id stretches to full window and does't see the previous code, and I only see the "ok2" button.

I hope I have explained my problem well :)

Python File

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder

builder = Builder.load_file("index.kv")

class mainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return builder


if __name__ == '__main__':
    mainApp().run()
```

.kv file

```
<Main>
ScreenManager:
    id: MainScreensManager
    Screen:
        name: "MainScreen"
        manager: 'MainScreensManager'
        BoxLayout:
            Label:
                text: "ok"
            Label:
                text: "ok1"
        BoxLayout:
            ScreenManager:
                id: ContentScreensManager
                Screen:
                    name: "FilmsScreen"
                    manager: "ContentScreensManager"
                    BoxLayout:
                        Button:
                            text: "ok2"
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default `size_hint` for any widget is `(1,1)`, which means it will cover the entire parent widget. So your `kv` will result in everything filling the entire `Screen`. That ends up with only the last thing drawn (the "ok2" button) being visible. So, you just need to set `size_hint` to values (or set `size_hint` to `None.None` and then set `size`). And you probably want to set `pos` or `pos_hint` also. Have a look at the [size_hint documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.widget.html?highlight=size_hint#kivy.uix.widget.Widget.size_hint_x).

Comment: Thanks! For some reason I thought that a Screen was already working as a container

Comment: The `Screen` is a container, it extends `RelativeLayout`.